# Testing legacy app in RoR - skip the DB tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I'm a PHP dev mostly and just starting out with Ruby, so please correct me if I say something dumb.

I'm working on fixing some bugs in a "legacy" app written in rails. The app itself has never been unit-tested. I can see the test scaffolding generated by rails but tests are nowhere to be found.

The app is pretty big and the code quality is very bad, so I wanted to write some units tests for the functionality I'll be fixing, before writing any code.

The problem is that when I run `rake test` command, the testing DB is created, but if I write any tests it keeps crashing on me. There are several problems with some relations and keys which I tried to fix, but more problems just keep appearing. I do understand that the DB is created with `schema.rb` file, but I'm sure it is just outdated by now. It is another issue I will maybe fix, but for now I just want to write some basic unit tests not even using the DB itself.

So the question is: is it possible to write just unit tests for some methods without invoking all the test DB scripts? I'm aware that this is maybe not the best practice, but I will feel better modifying the app with some test coverage and starting with fixing the DB I do not yet understand seems like a bad idea to me.

I'm using Ruby version 2.1.10 and the app is written in Rails 4.0.4 - these seem to be the latest versions I managed to run the app on.

Comment: _Sidenote_: `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:migrate` should bring your test DB in the recent up-to-date state.

Comment: To invoke the single unit test explicitly, use something like `bundle exec rspec spec/path/to/file_spec.rb` (the exact syntax depends on what testing suite is used in the project, usually it’s `rspec`.

Comment: Actually testunit/minitest have always been the default test tools in Rails. If you have a `/test` directory its minitest. If you are used to PHPUnit you'll feel a bit more at home with minitest as it has a pretty conventional syntax vs rspec which has a bit more learning of a learning curve.

Comment: I do have the `/test` directory. Fairly populated as well, because of scaffolding presumably. The problem is I cannot run even `assert true` type of test without running into database errors.